# press effect in JButton in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcombobox

when I am pressing a JButton in a JComboBox the press effect is not visible . please provide me with a solution.

Comment: Please add some code which presents that issue

Comment: Try to change the look & feel you are using.

Comment: A `JButton` in a `JComboBox` is only rendered as a button, but it will never act as a button. So why do you want to have buttons in your `JComboBox` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the arrow button, you could overwrite createArrowButton in the according UI class.

for Basic UI like this:

```
    public class MyComboBoxUI extends BasicComboBoxUI
{

    @Override
    protected JButton createArrowButton()
    {
        try
        {
            final JButton button = new JButton();
            //do whatever you like with the button
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            return super.createArrowButton();
        }
    }
 }
```

Then use yourComboBox.setUI(new MyComboBoxUI());